# Evaluation morphisms of formal power series and nilpotent elements

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series, abstract-algebra

Given a commutative ring $A$, and a finitely presented (associative) $A$-algebra $B$, show that a morphism of $A$-algebras $A[[x]] \longrightarrow B$  is given by evaluation at an nilpotent element $ \theta \in B$.

Comment: What have you learned just before this? What thoughts toward a solution have you had?

Comment: I don't know an answer, intuition tells me that if $\theta$ is not nilpotent then you have an element $\sum  a_n \theta^n$ and this is supposed to led to an absurd.

Comment: Possible point of confusion: In any ring (including rings of power series), one can only add finitely many elements together.

Comment: It is clear that the converse is true, given a nilpotent element $\theta \in B$ then the evaluation at $\theta$ defines a morphism of $A$-algebras, my question is if the converse is true, does the element has to be nilpotent in order to have such a morphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers a particular case of the question: when $B$ has only finitely many units.

Then if $\phi:A[[x]]\to B$ is a homomorphism of $A$-algebras and $\phi(x)=\theta$ we have that $1+\theta+\cdots+\theta^n$ is invertible for all $n\ge 0$. Since $B^{\times}$ is finite there exist $i<j$ such that $1+\theta+\cdots+\theta^i=1+\theta+\cdots+\theta^j$ and therefore $\theta^{i+1}(1+\theta+\cdots+\theta^{j-i-1})=0$. Since $1+\theta+\cdots+\theta^{j-i-1}$ is invertible we get $\theta^{i+1}=0$, that is, $\theta$ is nilpotent.

**Edit.** If I'm not mistaken, the claim of the problem is false: take $A=k[[y]]$, $B=A$, and $\phi:A[[x]]\to A$ defined by $\phi(x)=y$.

Comment: $A=k[[y]]$ is not a finitely presented $k$-algebra

Comment: @matiasdata In your question it's said that **$B$ is a finitely presented $A$-algebra**.

Comment: "and a finitely presented (associative) $A$-algebra $B$"

Comment: @matiasdata I think after so much time you are confused with your own question: $A$ is supposed to be any commutative ring and $B$ a finitely presented $A$-algebra. If $B=A$ is then $B$ a finitely presented $A$-algebra? Let me quote from Wiki (with the notation adapted to your question): "*If $A$ is a commutative ring and $B$ is an $A$-algebra, then $B$ is a finitely presented $A$-algebra if it is a quotient of a polynomial ring over $A$ in finitely many variables by a finitely generated ideal.*" Is this the case when $B=A$?

Comment: your answer is correct, the statement is false for a (general) commutative ring, although it is true under some extra hypothesis, thanks for the counterexample.

Comment: @matiasdata I've already pointed out in my answer that in some conditions the result holds true. But it would be nice if you can add some more examples.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ For all $\,a\in A,\,\ 1+ax\,$ is a unit, so its image $\, 1+a\theta\,$ is a unit for all $\,a\in A.$

Comment: I'm not sure if the hypothesis is the correct one. However, in this route, the jacobson ideal is equal to the nilradical if $B$ is Artinian, so this partially solves the problem. If $k$ is a field, then a $k$-algebra $B$ is artinian if and only if it is finitely generated as a $k$ vector space. Perhaps that's the correct hypothesis.

Comment: @matiasd That would do it :)

Comment: Dear @Bill : Looks like user121097 (in addition to me) is also having trouble seeing the link you intended from this solution to the answer to the question. I hope you find the time sometime soon to comment on our comments above. Thanks

Comment: @rschwieb Maybe we don't understand each other: if $B$ is an $A$-algebra, and $\theta\in B$ is such that $1+a\theta$ is invertible for all $a\in A$, why $\theta\in J(B)$?

Comment: Dear @user121097 Ah, I see your point. I had confabulated from another question that this was a surjection of $A$ onto $B$, but that is totally not the situation. Thanks for explaining clearly. So, I'm still in the dark about where this hint is going too. Regards